# How to verify if a Data stream already exists and delete or replace it ,in elasticsearch using python code

Tags: elasticsearch, rollover

This is how datastream is created
client.indices.create_data_stream(name=f'test_data_stream_{client}',error_trace=True)
client has authentication to elastic search
{client} is a dynamic value

I need to delete the data stream if it already exists and create a new one each time for a client.

How do I verify if datastream already exists then delete it or rollover using python code.

If I use client.indices.delete_data_stream(name=f'test_data_stream_{client}',error_trace=True) before creating, it throws an error if data stream is not previously created.

Comment: You can simply catch the error when deleting the data stream, that's why errors are for, it means "the data stream does not exist", so you can just go ahead and create it.